# i am making a test application in django and i want to submit the form when the time is over

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, django-forms, django-templates

this is my Html file and here I am trying to submit the form after 1 minute with all the values user has entered but the form is not posting any values

```
   <script>
   function countdown( elementName, minutes, seconds )
 {
var element, endTime, hours, mins, msLeft, time;

function twoDigits( n )
{
    return (n <= 9 ? "0" + n : n);
}

function updateTimer()
{
    msLeft = endTime - (+new Date);
    function submitform(){
        document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
        window.location.href = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/acceptAnswer";
      }
    if ( msLeft < 100 ) {
       
        submitform()
       
    } else {
        time = new Date( msLeft );
        hours = time.getUTCHours();
        mins = time.getUTCMinutes();
        element.innerHTML = (hours ? hours + ':' + twoDigits( mins ) : mins) + ':' + twoDigits( time.getUTCSeconds() );
        setTimeout( updateTimer, time.getUTCMilliseconds() + 500 );
    }
}

element = document.getElementById( elementName );
endTime = (+new Date) + 1000 * (60*minutes + seconds) + 500;
updateTimer();
}

 countdown( "ten-countdown", 1, 0 );</script>




 <div class="container" >
<div style="margin-left: 45%;" id="ten-countdown"></div>
<form id="myForm" action="{% url 'acceptAnswer' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for key, value in questions.items %} 
    
    
    {{key}}){{value.question}}
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="1" name="{{key}}" value="1">:{{value.option1}}<br>
    <input type="radio" id="2" name="{{key}}" value="2">:{{value.option2}}<br>
    <input type="radio" id="3" name="{{key}}" value="3">:{{value.option3}}<br>
    
    <input type="radio" id="4" name="{{key}}" value="4">:{{value.option4}}<br>
    
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

the form is getting submitted but the values are not getting posted empty form is getting posted

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you need to make sure, that at last one radio button is checked for the form send a value.

You can include a checked property in the radio button you want to be checked by default like

```
<input type="radio" id="1" name="{{key}}" value="1" checked>:{{value.option1}}
```